# Парсинг картинок на C#

Tags: c#, парсер

Есть небольшая проблема. При парсинге картинок, долго подгружаются изображения в PictureBox(разрешение 140х215, было бы чему грузится). Иногда быстро грузит, от чего зависит не знаю. Есть ли возможность подгружать их быстрее? Или же сохранять в кэш и после распределять по PictureBox'ам.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using HtmlDocument = HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument;

namespace ivi
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            GetHtmlAsync();
        }

        private async void GetHtmlAsync()
        {
            //Boxes
            PictureBox[] boxes = {
  pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4, pictureBox5, pictureBox6, pictureBox7, pictureBox8, pictureBox9, pictureBox10};
            Label[] labels = {
                label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10};

            //Parse
            var url = "https://www.ivi.ru/movies/horror";

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);

            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

            var ProductHtml = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("ul")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                .Equals("gallery posters-small mobile-has-titles js-criteo-gallery")).ToList();

            var ProductlistItems = ProductHtml[0].Descendants("li")
                .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                .Contains("poster")).ToList();
            int i = 0;

            //Список
            foreach (var ProducListItem in ProductlistItems)
            {
                //Название фильма
                var namefilm = ProducListItem.Descendants("span")
                    .Where(node => node.GetAttributeValue("class", "")
                    .Equals("name")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText.Trim();

                //Картинка фильма
                var picturefilm = ProducListItem.Descendants("img").FirstOrDefault().GetAttributeValue("src", "");

                //Logs
                LogText.Text += namefilm + '\r' + '\n';  
                LogText.Text += picturefilm + '\r' + '\n';

                boxes[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                boxes[i].ImageLocation = picturefilm;
                labels[i].Text = namefilm;
                i++;
                if (i == 9)
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может от сервера зависит?

Comment: Не факт. Картинка весит в среднем по 12 КБ..подгружаю максимум 10 картинок. Не думаю, что сервак 120 Кбайт долго подгрузит.

Comment: Метод вроде асинхронный, но вызывается без await. Вам IDE предупреждение не выдаёт?

Comment: Вы получаете весь список `ProductlistItems`, а потом вручную делаете `break` в цикле `foreach` (цикл `for` был бы уместней). Уберите `ToList`, добавьте `Take(10)`.

Comment: Попробуйте загружать изображения с помощью метода `PictureBox.LoadAsync`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не факт. Картинка весит в среднем по 12 КБ..подгружаю максимум 10 картинок. Не думаю, что сервак 120 Кбайт долго подгрузит.

Вопрос не в весе картинки, а в пинге сервера. Если по какой-то причине задержка на запрос увеличивается, то и 12 КБ будет долго качатся. Точнее качатся будет достаточно быстро, а вот начинать скачивание - долго.

Тебе нужно делать не последовательно запросы а в паралели. Это решит проблему скорости подгрузки. Открой для себя многопоточность и будет тебе счастье :)

Comment: Или лучше натянуть их какое то количество, 10 например, а потом сравнивать, паралельно качать следующие 10 - конвейер